# Ubuntu 17.10 GDM Auto-Login not working

Tags: 17.10, auto-login

I have selected the setting 'Automatic Login' from within the default Gnome 3 Ubuntu 17.10 control panel app, but it keeps resetting to 'off' after every restart and does not allow me to automatically login.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using nvidia drivers?

Comment: If not using nvidia drivers (on a desktop machine, laptops should be fine) post the contents of `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` also note that the setting in Settings > Details > Users acts like a cover, i.e. whatever you uncover is enabled, what you cover up is disabled.

Comment: I'm using it, this is my [`custom.conf`](https://gist.github.com/elect86/eaae9fbf73fce4ac0f28256be8750085)

Comment: I have tried using nvidia drivers but I am now using the open source drivers.

Comment: I have not touched the custom.conf

Comment: Custom.conf can be found here: [custom.conf](https://pastebin.com/3ruPW6zK)

Comment: Currently using the nouveau drivers

Comment: Can u pls finally tell me which answer solved your problem?  Because I have the same things.  Thanks.

Comment: The problem is the captial letter in the word True in the gdm3 custom.conf

Comment: "AutomaticLoginEnable=true" instead of "AutomaticLoginEnable=True"

Answer (score 14):

I had to force the loging screen to use xorg and not wayland (not yet supported by nvidia drivers).

Edit as root the file /etc/gdm3/custom.conf.

```
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

Change the line

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

to

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works for me in combination with:  AutomaticLoginEnable = true
AutomaticLogin = <my user name>

Answer (score 7):

I think i've found the problem, try to edit `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` 
and write `AutomaticLoginEnable=true` 
instead of `AutomaticLoginEnable=True` in my case

(full lowercase for the word "true")

or uncomment this line if it is...

Comment: I don't think it's necessary because my `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`is already "AutomaticLoginEnable=true" but it was commented. I just uncommented it.

Comment: In mine it was written AutomaticLoginEnable=True and I had never edited it manually.... Maybe it cal help some people if not you ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, even for me this solution worked, @Pöl Halbert... I uncommented, because it was `true`. But, switching in Details > Users panel, it turns `True`and `False`. Even changing `True`to `true`, autologin didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

For those who are desperate because it continues failing and failing despite using x11 and writing the proper configuration, are you using a docking station?
I figured that under X11, the docking station forces a login: it doesn't load the gdm automatic login settings. Surely a bug.
A workaround is to use the following config instead at `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` below the `[daemon]` section:

```
TimedLoginEnable=true
TimedLogin=<your_username>
TimedLoginDelay=0
```

It's not as handy as using Automatic Login but at least it works.
You can indeed keep the `AutomaticLogin` configs if that's already there, those will be loaded and used whenever the docking station is not plugged.
It's interesting to notice that Wayland behaves differently: AutomaticLogin does work with Wayland + docking station, but not with X11.
If you choose Wayland, beware that Wayland does not support the "share screen" button in many common video-call softwares.

EDIT: add some precisions following commentary.

Answer (score 2):

Same issue. I've originally changed the "/etc/gdm3/custom.conf" and simply enabled the "AutomaticLoginEnable=True". This was the whole issue: I didn't notice that "True" has to be lowercase.

EDIT: 
I was wrong. My autologin works because I'm NOT using the gnome-xorg (the default option for ubuntu) but the gnome classic session.
I can't manage to get the gnome-xorg session to work properly unless I setup a timedlogin which is a little unpleasant.

EDIT 2:
Ok, I finally got enough of this issue, since it's getting ignored. To solve my issue, since I don't care the least about gdm but I still want to use chrome, I've installed lightdm and changed the autologin in the user settings.

In other words:

```
sudo apt install lightdm
```

followed by the usual change in the user settings for the autologin.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that it's a bug in Settings app. When changing the 'Automatic Login' flag under Details->Users it writes True/False values for `AutomaticLoginEnable` in "/etc/gdm3/custom.conf".
After manually writing the value `AutomaticLoginEnable=true` the auto-login works.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.
The AutomaticLoginEnable=true was remarked out in the file, but activating it, didn't change anything.

Comment: @SimonRigét - as you already wrote in your answer, both variables are required for auto-login:  `AutomaticLoginEnable` and `AutomaticLogin` with username. The Settings app writes both variables, but the bug is that it writes True/False with capital letters.

Comment: This solution didn't work for me, @Julius and @SimonRigét, not regarding if it's `true`or `True`, the result is the same: nothing works. These two statements are present in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`: `AutomaticLoginEnable` and `AutomaticLogin`

Comment: And 2 years later this is still an issue...

Answer (score 0):

I had to set two variables, to make it work:

```
$sudo gedit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

And insert the lines:

```
AutomaticLoginEnable = true
AutomaticLogin = <my user name>
```

The settings app is buggy, to an extend where it's getting useless as of 11.2017. Hopefuly that will change :)

Answer (score 0):

I just had problems with **GDM 3.28.3 auto login** with **18.04 minimal** and `gnome-core` only. GUI froze completely on boot with the error `A start job is running for Hold until boot process finishes up` and after long research I accidentally found a solution by disabling the boot splash screen:

```
# disable splash screen on boot
sudo sed -i 's/splash quiet//g' /etc/default/grub
sudo update-grub
```

**Note:** To enable the splash again: `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` and make sure `splash quiet` is again within the quotation marks of `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` e.g. `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash quiet"`. Apply the new settings with `sudo update-grub`.

I hope this saves other people's time. If anyone has an idea why this worked for me please let me know.