# How to restart GDM3 with autologin on 18.04 and 19.04

Tags: 18.04, gdm, auto-login, 19.04

On Ubuntu 16.04 with lightdm, and an autologin account, I can restart the graphical session with command :

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

The account logs in automatically.

On Ubuntu 18.04 (and also on 19.04), the same autologin account is setup, but the command :

```
sudo service gdm3 restart
```

fails to autologin, and bring the display to the login page.

In gdm logs, I can find

```
systemd[1]: gdm.service: Succeeded.
systemd[1]: Stopped GNOME Display Manager.
systemd[1]: Starting GNOME Display Manager...
systemd[1]: Started GNOME Display Manager.
gdm-autologin][4091]: gkr-pam: no password is available for user
gdm-autologin][4091]: pam_unix(gdm-autologin:session): session opened for user screen by (uid=0)
gdm-autologin][4091]: gkr-pam: couldn't unlock the login keyring.
```

How to properly restart the user session, with autologin user logged in on ubuntu 18.04 ?

Comment: Could you add the output of `journalctl -xn`?

Comment: Here are the logs of this command : https://pastebin.com/raw/FvNMN7ek

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 17.10 GDM Auto-Login not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967847/ubuntu-17-10-gdm-auto-login-not-working)

Comment: No, autologin works at boot, it's just not autologin when gdm3 is restarted

Comment: I'll retract that vote then!

Answer (score 8):

Had the same issue, I solved it by enabling 'Timed Login' in the /etc/gdm3/custom.conf file. Mine looks like:

```
# GDM configuration storage
#
# See /usr/share/gdm/gdm.schemas for a list of available options.

[daemon]
AutomaticLoginEnable=true
AutomaticLogin=username

# Uncoment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
#WaylandEnable=false

# Enabling automatic login

# Enabling timed login
TimedLoginEnable = true
TimedLogin = username
TimedLoginDelay = 10

[security]

[xdmcp]

[chooser]

[debug]
# Uncomment the line below to turn on debugging
# More verbose logs
# Additionally lets the X server dump core if it crashes
#Enable=true
```

Comment: On my RPi-4 it's `/etc/gdm3/daemon.conf`, FYI.

Answer (score 1):

Slight change to Celly's answer above. The default, or OOB, custom.conf file has the AutomaticLoginEnable and AutomaticLogin parameters commented out. I left those parameters commented out and uncommented/set TimedLoginEnable, TimedLogin, and TimedLoginDelay. It still works. Thank-you Celly!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be fixed on Ubuntu 20.04 : gdm3 service restart will result in successful autologin.