# 19.04 boots to flashing cursor after windows memory management bsod

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 19.04, boot-repair

I installed Ubuntu 19.04 on my windows 10 machine this weekend with no problems. On my first windows boot since the Ubuntu install I got a memory management bsod after which windows booted up fine. However I havn't been able to successfully boot up Ubuntu since. I get a flashing cursor. I can hit ctrl+alt+f2 and log in, but I don't know what to do after this. I tried using boot repair which changed the boot menu but hasn't fixed the problem. The URL it gave me is http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/DYqmGMzQWc/ It also told me to make my BIOS boot on sda2/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi file, but I'm not sure how to do that. Thanks for any help!

Update:
I tried purging and reinstalling grub2 using instructions from here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing and I keep getting stuck with an error message "dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting: files list file for package 'linux-image-generic' is missing final newline" Is this related?

Comment: Fast boot disabled? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/532622/323121

Comment: That didn't seem to help. Don't think it's fast boot related.

Comment: It's not grub but X. Will write in a bit... Need to run

Answer (score 0):

This is more ongoing debugging session than an answer

## Your Linux is up

If c-a-f2 gives you a login... Which means **if**

- logout (ctrl-d) followed by again login works
- ls works
- apt/apt-get work

**Then**

- shell is working
- basic utilities are ok
- kernel is ok
- grub is ok

Currently it looks like

1. Apt (data) is not fine
2. X ([lightdm](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM))
   is not starting ok
3. Efi issue

I'm not up to recent Ubuntu...Here's the older solutions. You may want to open new focussed questions

1. apt-get update... apt-get -f
2. service lightdm restart...check X logs
3. Image/text-copy/photograph efi message

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Sorry I've been away for a few days. Looks like the conditions you mentioned all check out. I was able to run "apt-get update" but "service lightdm restart" failed with a message "Failed to restart lightdm.service: Unit lighten.service not found". What more focused question would be good to ask at this point?

Comment: Cut paste it cmd+response into question. If can't then hand copy!

Comment: Pls chk current display manager https://vitux.com/some-common-ubuntu-display-managers-and-how-to-switch-between-them/

Comment: It's using gdm3. I tried to run "sudo apt-get install lightdm" as mentioned in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1050672/gdm3-does-not-start-in-ubuntu-18-04 to switch to lightdm but ran into that same missing newline at end of file thing I've run into before.

Comment: Don't worry abt apt. Try sudo service restart gdm. And copy errors if/as they appear. Or gdm3... Which ever...

Comment: It comes back with "restart: unrecognized service" when I tried "sudo service restart gdm3". But when I tried "sudo service gdm3 restart" nothing happened at all, just moved on to the next prompt. Ctrl+alt+f7 still does nothing

Comment: Does service gdm3 stop make blinking cursor (on ctrl-alt-f7) vanish?

Comment: I think time to move onto a focussed gdm/apt question https://askubuntu.com/q/1136457/358822

Comment: Nope, ctrl-alt-7 makes no difference on the screen at all. You're probably right. I'll post a new one tomorrow.