# Ubuntu 19.10 can't switch to xorg session from wayland

Tags: 19.10

I changed /etc/gdm3/custom.conf as mentioned on [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967847/ubuntu-17-10-gdm-auto-login-not-working), rebooted, but if i run `$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` it still says I'm running a wayland session. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you logged in under "Ubuntu" or "Ubuntu with Wayland"?

Comment: I'm logged under Ubuntu.

Comment: Restarted the computer and now it's working, so, thanks, I guess.

Comment: Yes, a reboot is required. I have similar answers as your link, but my answers includes the reboot. Good luck!