# Autologin and automatic screen lock methods not working (Ubuntu 22.04.3)

Tags: 22.04, lock-screen, auto-login

I can't seem to get what is described in this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181265/automated-login-and-screen-lock) to work... I even tried entering the command into the terminal, but all I get is command not found.

I have also tried the startup applications method as described in the same thread, but that only results in an error occurring upon boot along with ubuntu wanting to send a report on it.

The lock button up to the right functions as intended though, so I'm guessing things have changed since the referred to post was made. Does anyone here happen to know how to solve this issue?

---

Update: Did as instructed by one of the subcomments and installed gnome-screensaver (and it still doesn't work).

---

Update 2: Uninstalled gnome-screensaver since xdg is apparently what handles the lock screen by default. xdg-screensaver lock works from terminal, but not from startup applications.

---

Update 3: Made a folder called .startup in "/home/insertusername/", and then ran I made a file called AutoLock.sh w. the contents of that being the following (ignore the empty rows in between each row):

> !/bin/bash
>
> xdg-screensaver lock

I then ran "chmod +x AutoLock.sh && chmod -w Autolock.sh". I followed that up by then adding the path for .sh-file into my .desktop file (lockscreen.desktop) within "/home/insertusername/.config/autostart/", and the contents of that is:

> [Desktop Entry]
>
> Type=Application
>
> Name=AutoLock
>
> Exec=/home/glacier/.startup/autostart.sh
>
> X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false

Doesn't work.

---

Update 4: Tried adding sleep 1 into the bash script as instructed, making it look like:

> #!/bin/bash
>
> sleep 1
>
> xdg-screensaver lock

Doesn't work either.

---

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 17.10 GDM Auto-Login not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967847/ubuntu-17-10-gdm-auto-login-not-working)

Comment: GNOME3 doesn't use gnome-screensaver. Use AutomaticLoginEnable in the linked answer

Comment: The issue isn't automatic login (that functions as intended), and I need it for gnome remote desktop to work. The issue is that the provided methods for making it go to the lock screen after booting up doesn't work.

I tried applying the xdg equivalent of gnome-screensaver, as I later described in what is update 2, but that didn't work either.

What do I do now?

Comment: Does `loginctl lock-session` work?

Comment: Niope, same thing. It works from the terminal, but not from within startup applications.

Comment: What are the file contents and filepath you are using? Does adding a `sleep 1` work?

Comment: How should I format it, should I just write "sleep 1 xdg-screensaver lock" (without quotation marks)?

Comment: I would create a bash script with those commands, add a hashbang, mark as executable, then put the absolute path in the desktop file, just to be safe

Comment: Added two updates in the post of what I tried during the previous hours were you and I were writing one another, and I included your suggested edit as well. I also tried just making another entry into the startup application preferences, while turning off the other one, and simply entered "sleep 1 xdg-screensaver lock" (didn't work either).

Comment: I also tried putting the same file in /etc/profile.d/, but that only ended up with a prompt telling me lock was an unknown command and that I should remedy the issue as soon as possible... I then tried replacing the "xdg-screensaver lock" command with the "loginctl lock-session" that you mentioned earler, but that just did nothing through this method.