# Need further assistance with implementing autologin followed by an automatic lock screen function (Ubuntu 22.04.3)

Tags: startup, lock-screen, startup-applications, execute-command, auto-login

I made [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1503012/autologin-and-automatic-screen-lock-methods-not-working-ubuntu-22-04-3) previously, and I have provided a thorough description of what I want to achieve along with every step I've made towards trying to make it work. The post seems to have died, and I have had no engagement since February 10:th, so I am going against my better judgement and making this post with the hope of it attracting more than just one person towards helping me solve the issue at hand.

Feel free to share a solution if anyone here happens to know what I've been doing wrong so far... I'm hoping that this is just a user error situation, since it would at least have a solution then.